# Svelte with prettier/eslint

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, svelte, prettier

I am trying to make an app using svelte to try it out.

I would like to setup prettier and eslint, I installed those dependencies and the extension for Svelte for VS Code.

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^2.7.3",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^1.1.0",
    "save-dev": "0.0.1-security",
    "sirv-cli": "^1.0.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.6.1"
  }
```

Now, I am having trouble setting everything up.

I made

.eslintrc

```json
{
  "plugins": ["eslint-plugin-svelte3"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": "error"
  }
}
```

.prettierrc

```json
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es6"
}
```

and I would like autosave with settings.json under .vscode

```json
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    "source.fixAll.prettier": true
  },
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
  "eslint.validate": ["svelte"]
}
```

Now I tried to use this, but nothing happen when I save, neither when I execute

```json
"fix": "npx eslint --fix \"src/**/*.svelte\"",
"format": "npx prettier --write \"src/**/*.svelte\""
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: There's an extension for it: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode

Comment: @Daniel_Knights > and the extension for Svelte for VS Code. 

I already have it

Comment: @Bobby Could you try with this `.eslintrc` config: https://github.com/johannchopin/gitmoji-browser-extension/blob/master/.eslintrc

Answer (score 30):

The formatting problems occur because in your settings you tell VSCode to format everything with the `esbenp.prettier-vscode` extension, which cannot handle Svelte files. Add this to your config and it should work.

```json
  "[svelte]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "svelte.svelte-vscode"
  },
```

As an alternative you can install `prettier-plugin-svelte` from npm. After a reload, Prettier will notice this plugin if it's in the same `node_modules` folder and defer formatting of Svelte file to it. This should also fix your "Svelte files do not get formatted when running `npm run format`" problem.

For reference:
https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/tree/master/docs#my-code-does-not-get-formatted

The ESLint problem likely occurs because the plugin name is wrong and you are missing the `overrides` section which tells ESLint how to treat Svelte files:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'svelte3'
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.svelte'],
      processor: 'svelte3/svelte3'
    }
  ],
  ..
};
```

Reference for setup: https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3#installation

Answer (score 10):

The `eslint-plugin-svelte3` is **deprecated**, instead it's recommended to use `eslint-plugin-svelte`.

[From official SVELTEJS repository](https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3#installation) :

> This ESLint plugin is deprecated.
> eslint-plugin-svelte is the new official ESLint plugin for Svelte.

**FOLLOW THESE STEPS**

***FYI my configuration are based on [sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/creating-a-project) (I am using a svelte/vite project)***

1/ **Check** if [prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) & [svelte vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) extensions are installed in your `vscode`.

2/ **Install** these packages :

```
pnpm i -D eslint prettier eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-svelte prettier-plugin-svelte
```

- I use `pnpm` package manager, but you can use `npm` or `yarn`.
- `-D` only means installed in `devDependencies`
- `eslint-config-prettier` is **useful** for `eslint` & `prettier` work well together
- `eslint-plugin-svelte` & `prettier-plugin-svelte` are needed to easily manage **svelte** files

3/ **Initialize** these `eslint` & `prettier` configuration files :

`.eslintrc.cjs` (I use `.cjs` but you can use any of extension supported by `eslint`)

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:svelte/recommended', 'prettier'],
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    extraFileExtensions: ['.svelte'],
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2017: true,
    node: true,
  },
};
```

`.prettierrc`  (I use `.prettierrc` but you can use any name supported by `prettier`)

```
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "semi": true,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-svelte"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.svelte",
      "options": {
        "parser": "svelte"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- you can set your own preferred code style, but the **most important parts** are `plugins` & `overrides`.

`.eslintignore` (optional but useful for `git`)

```
.DS_Store
node_modules
/dist
.env
.env.*
!.env.example

# Ignore files for PNPM, NPM and YARN
pnpm-lock.yaml
package-lock.json
yarn.lock
```

`.prettierignore` (optional but useful for `git`)

```
.DS_Store
node_modules
/dist
/package
.env
.env.*
!.env.example

# Ignore files for PNPM, NPM and YARN
pnpm-lock.yaml
package-lock.json
yarn.lock
```

4/ **Add** this in your `.vscode/settings.json` :

```
{
  ...
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript", "svelte"],
  ...
}
```

5/ **Add** script in your `package.json` in order to format all your JS/HTML/(S)CSS/SVELTE files in one command :

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "format": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --write ."
},
```

6/ **check** your VS Code settings (both global and workspace) to make sure that the default formatter for Svelte files is set to Prettier.

7/ **Restart** your `vscode`

8/ **Test** if it works with the command line `pnpm format` (or `npm run format` or `yarn format`)

**BONUS** :

If you want to auto-format your code, when saving a file, add this line in your `.vscode/settings.json` :

```
{
  ...
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: Finally got it to work in a monorepo with JS, TSX and Svelte. This should be marked as the correct answer.