# How can I use prettier with Typescript's new 'satisfies' operator?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, prettier

> *Quick note: this isn't anything to do with .svelte files, which are answered in other questions like [Svelte with prettier/eslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63425920/svelte-with-prettier-eslint). Rather it's about plain TS 4.9, which happens to be used in SvelteKit.*

When I use the exact function from [the Svelte API route docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server):

```js
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types';

export const GET = (({ url }) => {
  const min = Number(url.searchParams.get('min') ?? '0');
  const max = Number(url.searchParams.get('max') ?? '1');

  const d = max - min;

  if (isNaN(d) || d < 0) {
    throw error(400, 'min and max must be numbers, and min must be less than max');
  }

  const random = min + Math.random() * d;

  return new Response(String(random));
}) satisfies RequestHandler;
```

Prettier doesn't like the [new-ish TypeScript `satisfies` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
["ERROR" - 3:54:50 PM] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 3:54:50 PM] ',' expected. (17:4)
  15 |
  16 |   return new Response(String(random));
> 17 | }) satisfies RequestHandler;
     |    ^
  18 |
SyntaxError: ',' expected. (17:4)
```

I've tried upgrading to the latest prettier but this hasn't resolved the problem:

```
$ npm ls | grep prettier
├── eslint-config-prettier@8.3.0
├── prettier-plugin-svelte@2.10.1
├── prettier@2.8.8
```

And the latest TypeScript:

```
$ npm ls | grep typescript
├── @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.59.11
├── @typescript-eslint/parser@5.59.11
├── typescript@5.1.3
```

Full errors including my config is below:

```
["INFO" - 3:54:50 PM] Formatting file:///home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/src/routes/api/v1/proposals/%2Bserver.ts
["INFO" - 3:54:50 PM] Using config file at '/home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 3:54:50 PM] Using ignore file (if present) at /home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/.prettierignore
["INFO" - 3:54:50 PM] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "typescript"
}
["INFO" - 3:54:50 PM] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 3:54:50 PM] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "/home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/src/routes/api/v1/proposals/+server.ts",
  "parser": "typescript",
  "useTabs": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "printWidth": 120,
  "proseWrap": "always",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "semi": true,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "svelteSortOrder": "options-scripts-markup-styles",
  "svelteStrictMode": false,
  "svelteBracketNewLine": true,
  "svelteAllowShorthand": true
}
["ERROR" - 3:54:50 PM] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 3:54:50 PM] ',' expected. (17:4)
  15 |
  16 |   return new Response(String(random));
> 17 | }) satisfies RequestHandler;
     |    ^
  18 |
SyntaxError: ',' expected. (17:4)
  15 |
  16 |   return new Response(String(random));
> 17 | }) satisfies RequestHandler;
     |    ^
  18 |
    at e (/home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/node_modules/prettier/parser-typescript.js:1:322)
    at /home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/node_modules/prettier/parser-typescript.js:22:3328487
    at Object.parse (/home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/node_modules/prettier/parser-typescript.js:22:3328520)
    at Object.parse$a [as parse] (/home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/node_modules/prettier/index.js:12513:19)
    at coreFormat (/home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/node_modules/prettier/index.js:14044:16)
    at formatWithCursor$1 (/home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/node_modules/prettier/index.js:14284:14)
    at /home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/node_modules/prettier/index.js:59304:12
    at Object.format (/home/mike/Code/mycompany/myproject/node_modules/prettier/index.js:59324:12)
    at t.default.format (/home/mike/.vscode-server/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.13.0/dist/extension.js:1:14694)
    at t.PrettierEditProvider.provideEdits (/home/mike/.vscode-server/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.13.0/dist/extension.js:1:11367)
    at U.provideDocumentFormattingEdits (/home/mike/.vscode-server/bin/4cb974a7aed77a74c7813bdccd99ee0d04901215/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:102:45790)
["INFO" - 3:54:50 PM] Formatting completed in 82ms.
```

Comment: Are you using babel to compile your TS?

Comment: @adsy nope, not using Babel.

Comment: Seemingly dumb question but have you restarted your editor after upgrading ts/prettier?